# How to make a program to accept a name and print only the middle name in python

Tags: python, windows, debugging

[See this code :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuu0N.gif)

```
a= 'Ram Mohan Roy'

z = len (a)

i = 0

for i in z(0):
    b = a[i]
    if i== " ":
        break
i += i
k = i
for k in a(z):
    s = a[i:k]
    if (s[-1]) == " ":
        break

print(s)
```

The question is : How to make a program to accept a name & print only the middle name.
    p.s. I know io have assigned the name & not accepted it.

please tell me the correct working program in Python.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post a [mre]. A picture of some code is not appropriate.

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty. No error checks.

```
name = input("\n Please enter your full name: (first middle last) ")
name_list = name.split()
print(name_list[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is really open, you should include your code here, however, assuming that the input is clean you could make something like this

```
In [3]: def middle_name(name: str) -> str:
   ...:     name_split = name.split(' ')
   ...:     return name_split[1]
   ...:

In [4]: middle_name('Jose Angel Sanchez')
Out[4]: 'Angel'
```